# How to align 4 circles

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, alignment

I am trying to align these 4 circles ( top 2 circle below that 2 circle). I tried changing the margin style it fails and it is creating 4 circles vertically. I need 2 circles at the top below that 2 circle should be there at the right side of the webpage. Can anyone help how to align these 4 circle horizontally 2*2.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("Canvas").getContext("2d");
const ctx2 = document.getElementById("Canvas2").getContext("2d");
const ctx3 = document.getElementById("Canvas3").getContext("2d");
const ctx4 = document.getElementById("Canvas4").getContext("2d");
const containerR = 80;
const size = containerR * 2
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = size;
ctx2.canvas.width = ctx2.canvas.height = size;
ctx3.canvas.width = ctx3.canvas.height = size;
ctx4.canvas.width = ctx4.canvas.height = size;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;
ctx2.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx3.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx4.globalAlpha = 0.8;

const getBall = (x, y, dx, dy, r, color) => ({x, y, dx, dy, r, color});
const balls = [
  getBall(size / 2, size - 30, -0.1, -0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 3, size - 50, 0.1, 0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 4, size - 60, -0.1, 0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5,  0.1, 0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5,  0.1, -0.1, 4, "Green"),
];
const drawBall = (ball) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx2.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx2.fill();
  ctx2.closePath();
  ctx3.beginPath();
  ctx3.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx3.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx3.fill();
  ctx3.closePath();
  ctx4.beginPath();
  ctx4.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx4.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx4.fill();
  ctx4.closePath();
}
const updatePos = (ball) => {

  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;
  const dx = ball.x - containerR;
  const dy = ball.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - ball.r) {
    const v = Math.sqrt(ball.dx * ball.dx + ball.dy * ball.dy);
    const angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    const oldAngle = Math.atan2(-ball.dy, ball.dx);
    const newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    ball.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    ball.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}
const collides = (a, b) => (Math.hypot(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y)) < (a.r + b.r));
function engine() {
  //console.clear(); // Clear console test messages
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, ctx2.canvas.width, ctx2.canvas.height);
  ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, ctx3.canvas.width, ctx3.canvas.height);
  ctx4.clearRect(0, 0, ctx4.canvas.width, ctx4.canvas.height);



  balls.forEach((a, ai) => {
    a.collider = undefined;
    
    balls.forEach((b, bi) => {
      if (bi === ai) return; // Don't look at self
      if (collides(a, b)) a.collider = b; // Store the colliding B ball
    });
    updatePos(a);
    drawBall(a);
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}
engine();
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas" 
  style = "background: #eee;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 60%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
  align-content: right;"></canvas>
<canvas id ="Canvas2"
  style = "background: #eee;
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-left: 60%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
  align-content: right;"></canvas>
  <canvas id ="Canvas3"
  style = "background: #eee;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-left: 75%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
  align-content: right;"></canvas>
  <canvas id ="Canvas4"
  style = "background: #eee;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-left: 75%;
  margin-bottom: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
  align-content: right;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Could you use a table? Each cell holding a circle and no border to the cells. This should put it in the 2 x 2 formation, if you use 2 rows with 2 cells per row. Then just position the table.

Comment: @BrendenPrice Suggesting a table layout in 2020 with should a easy to create grid is bad advice. We moved on from table since layouts 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the layout I used some CSS flexbox features, within these features it's possible to align them on all possible ways.

Learn more about flexbox here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox and see my example for a quick start.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("Canvas").getContext("2d");
const ctx2 = document.getElementById("Canvas2").getContext("2d");
const ctx3 = document.getElementById("Canvas3").getContext("2d");
const ctx4 = document.getElementById("Canvas4").getContext("2d");
const containerR = 80;
const size = containerR * 2
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = size;
ctx2.canvas.width = ctx2.canvas.height = size;
ctx3.canvas.width = ctx3.canvas.height = size;
ctx4.canvas.width = ctx4.canvas.height = size;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;
ctx2.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx3.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx4.globalAlpha = 0.8;

const getBall = (x, y, dx, dy, r, color) => ({
  x,
  y,
  dx,
  dy,
  r,
  color
});
const balls = [
  getBall(size / 2, size - 30, -0.1, -0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 3, size - 50, 0.1, 0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 4, size - 60, -0.1, 0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5, 0.1, 0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5, 0.1, -0.1, 4, "Green"),
];
const drawBall = (ball) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx2.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx2.fill();
  ctx2.closePath();
  ctx3.beginPath();
  ctx3.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx3.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx3.fill();
  ctx3.closePath();
  ctx4.beginPath();
  ctx4.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx4.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx4.fill();
  ctx4.closePath();
}
const updatePos = (ball) => {

  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;
  const dx = ball.x - containerR;
  const dy = ball.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - ball.r) {
    const v = Math.sqrt(ball.dx * ball.dx + ball.dy * ball.dy);
    const angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    const oldAngle = Math.atan2(-ball.dy, ball.dx);
    const newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    ball.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    ball.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}
const collides = (a, b) => (Math.hypot(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y)) < (a.r + b.r));

function engine() {
  //console.clear(); // Clear console test messages
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, ctx2.canvas.width, ctx2.canvas.height);
  ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, ctx3.canvas.width, ctx3.canvas.height);
  ctx4.clearRect(0, 0, ctx4.canvas.width, ctx4.canvas.height);



  balls.forEach((a, ai) => {
    a.collider = undefined;

    balls.forEach((b, bi) => {
      if (bi === ai) return; // Don't look at self
      if (collides(a, b)) a.collider = b; // Store the colliding B ball
    });
    updatePos(a);
    drawBall(a);
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}
engine();
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#Canvas, #Canvas2, #Canvas3, #Canvas4 {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 4px #000;
    margin: 10px;
}

.canvas-holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="canvas-holder">
      <canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
      <span>Circle one</span>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas-holder">
      <canvas id="Canvas2"></canvas>
      <span>Circle two</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="canvas-holder">
      <canvas id="Canvas3"></canvas>
      <span>Circle tree</span>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas-holder">
      <canvas id="Canvas4"></canvas>
      <span>Circle four</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm aware this is not the perfect way to implement this layout but I also wanted to make a example using the flex-direction: column; to spark the interest of learning how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help and vision...its really works...how to add text at bottom of the circle?

Comment: @Anonymous You can add another div around the canvas tag and place the text in there . And style it accordingly.

Comment: i added div tag around canvas tag but it comes at the topright even i entered text-align: bottom . So can you add code snippet for that?

Comment: text-align: bottom, doesn't exist. Please checkout the provided link to learn more about flexbox :-) you will need to get better at CSS, https://www.w3schools.com/css/ I edit my answer to include your request.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest moving your styles to CSS to reduce repeated styles.

For example:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("Canvas").getContext("2d");
const ctx2 = document.getElementById("Canvas2").getContext("2d");
const ctx3 = document.getElementById("Canvas3").getContext("2d");
const ctx4 = document.getElementById("Canvas4").getContext("2d");
const containerR = 80;
const size = containerR * 2
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = size;
ctx2.canvas.width = ctx2.canvas.height = size;
ctx3.canvas.width = ctx3.canvas.height = size;
ctx4.canvas.width = ctx4.canvas.height = size;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;
ctx2.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx3.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx4.globalAlpha = 0.8;

const getBall = (x, y, dx, dy, r, color) => ({x, y, dx, dy, r, color});
const balls = [
  getBall(size / 2, size - 30, -0.1, -0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 3, size - 50, 0.1, 0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 4, size - 60, -0.1, 0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5,  0.1, 0.1, 4, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5,  0.1, -0.1, 4, "Green"),
];
const drawBall = (ball) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx2.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx2.fill();
  ctx2.closePath();
  ctx3.beginPath();
  ctx3.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx3.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx3.fill();
  ctx3.closePath();
  ctx4.beginPath();
  ctx4.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx4.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx4.fill();
  ctx4.closePath();
}
const updatePos = (ball) => {

  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;
  const dx = ball.x - containerR;
  const dy = ball.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - ball.r) {
    const v = Math.sqrt(ball.dx * ball.dx + ball.dy * ball.dy);
    const angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    const oldAngle = Math.atan2(-ball.dy, ball.dx);
    const newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    ball.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    ball.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}
const collides = (a, b) => (Math.hypot(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y)) < (a.r + b.r));
function engine() {
  //console.clear(); // Clear console test messages
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, ctx2.canvas.width, ctx2.canvas.height);
  ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, ctx3.canvas.width, ctx3.canvas.height);
  ctx4.clearRect(0, 0, ctx4.canvas.width, ctx4.canvas.height);



  balls.forEach((a, ai) => {
    a.collider = undefined;
    
    balls.forEach((b, bi) => {
      if (bi === ai) return; // Don't look at self
      if (collides(a, b)) a.collider = b; // Store the colliding B ball
    });
    updatePos(a);
    drawBall(a);
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}
engine();
```

```css
.canvas-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.canvas-wrapper div {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.canvas-wrapper  canvas {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
  max-width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrapper">
  <div><canvas id="Canvas"></canvas></div>
  <div><canvas id ="Canvas2"></canvas></div>
  <div><canvas id ="Canvas3"></canvas></div>
  <div><canvas id ="Canvas4"></canvas></div>
</div>
```